# Iteration on result of a sql

Tags: oracle11g

I am having a result from one sql. For ex: select * from employee.
I want to iterate for each record of the above the sql and update a column of the employee table with differrent values.I am using ORACLE database.
My code as of now is:

```
 DECLARE
      CURSOR cur_schedule_parameter
   IS
      SELECT schedule_parameter_type (PARM_TYP_CD,
                                  PARM_OPERAND_1_VAL,
                                  PARM_OPERAND_2_VAL,
                                  SCHED_ID,
                                  SCHED_PARM_ID,
                                  VOID_EVNT_ID,
                                  PARM_OPER_TYP_CD,
                                  ADD_EVNT_ID)
    FROM SCHEDULE_PARAMETER
   WHERE parm_operand_1_val IN ('C|S', 'S|C');

   v_sched_param_array   schedule_parameter_type_tab;
BEGIN
   IF cur_schedule_parameter%ISOPEN
   THEN
  CLOSE cur_schedule_parameter;
   END IF;

   OPEN cur_schedule_parameter;

   FETCH cur_schedule_parameter BULK COLLECT INTO v_sched_param_array;

  FOR indx IN v_sched_param_array.COUNT
   LOOP
       UPDATE SCHEDULE_PARAMETER
     SET VOID_EVNT_ID = indx
   WHERE SCHED_PARM_ID = v_sched_param_array (indx).SCHED_PARM_ID;

          END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
  NULL;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
  NULL;
   END;
```

I created type schedule_parameter_type and schedule_paraeter_type_tab (collection array).
Could you please suggest me how can I do this?

Comment: Please be more specific and add examples and also add what you have right now.

Comment: @realspirituals: I am using cursor as shown in my code. while running this procedure, I am getting an error saying v_sched_param_array is not of type cursor.

Comment: `v_sched_param_array   schedule_parameter_type_tab;` what is this

Comment: @realspirituals : V_sched_param_array is variable name to my collection array schedule_parameter_type_tab. I am fetching the sql result to this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while writing for loop we need to give as follows in my example which I missed previously

```
FOR indx IN 1 .. v_sched_param_array.COUNT
   LOOP
       UPDATE SCHEDULE_PARAMETER
     SET VOID_EVNT_ID = indx
   WHERE SCHED_PARM_ID = v_sched_param_array (indx).SCHED_PARM_ID;

      END LOOP;
```

Please let me know if my answer is not help.